# Activiti + Spring

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I have a component defined in Spring application that needs to be referenced from Activiti, the component name contains dots in the middle, how can I reference the bean name ?

Component

```
@Component("com.example.LoadUserData")
public class LoadUserData extends ActivitiAPI
```

Activiti model:

```
<serviceTask id="loadUserData" name="Load User Data" activiti:expression="#{com.example.LoadUserData}">
```

Comment: which el expression parser are you using?

Comment: I didn't change any default configuration for activiti, I am using activiti with Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

I havent actually attempted to use a bean with "dots" in the name within an expression so I'm not certain why this is failing.(What is the error you are getting?)

However, if it is failing, I imagine if you create an Activiti JavaDelegate class to wrap your logic and then autowire your bean into the class.
Likely not exactly what you are looking for, but will move you forward.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I have declared a Spring bean with @Service annotation like below

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.chvps.message.model.Document;
@Service
public class EnricherTask {
public void execute(Document document) {
        System.out.println("Enricher task executed");
    }

}
```

Use the same bean in activiti like below

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask2" name="Enrich Task" activiti:expression="#{enricherTask.execute(document)}"></serviceTask>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to configure a serviceTask.

if you want to use `serviceTask`, You can do it the following way

#### implement `org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate`

```
@Slf4j
public class MyServiceTask implements JavaDelegate {

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        log.info("MyServiceTask");
    }
}
```

#### Configure it in a BPMN file

```
<process id="my-process">
    <startEvent id="start"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="serviceTask"/>
    <serviceTask id="serviceTask" name="serviceTask" activiti:class="com.test.activiti.MyServiceTask"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="serviceTask" targetRef="end"/>
    <endEvent id="end"/>
</process>
```

Then your serviceTask will work, You don't need to inject it into the spring container and `activiti:expression`